# What is the difference between textureLodOffset and texelFetchOffset with respect to their expected offsets?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I know that `texelFetch` performs a lookup using texture coordinates with range `[0, textureSize]`, and `textureLod` with range `[0,1]` both with explicit level of detail.
But I have noticed that [`textureLodOffset`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/textureLodOffset.xhtml) requires an offset as `ivec2`, `int` and so on. This seems to be the case for [`texelFetchOffset`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/texelFetchOffset.xhtml) as well.
I can see why this makes sense for `texelFetch`, but I am not sure how it relates to `textureLod`.

I am used to computing the offset coordinate manually in the shader with something like `coord.xy + 1/textureSize()` for `textureLod`. I don't think this is causing any issues with performance etc, but I would like to know how we can use `textureLodOffset` with integer coordinates as specified in the documentation what makes their use different from `texelFetchOffset`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between [`textureLodOffset`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/textureLodOffset.xhtml) and [`texelFetchOffset`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/texelFetchOffset.xhtml) are the texture coordinates.
The texture coordinates of `textureLodOffset` are in rage [0, 1]. But the unit of the texture coordinates of `texelFetchOffset` are texels and the range of the coordinates depends on the size of the texture. In compare to the `*Fetch*` functions, `textureLodOffset` respects [texture filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_filtering) and sampling.
The `*Fetch*` functions performs a lookup of a single texel from an unambiguous texture coordinate. See [OpenGL 4.6 API Compatibility Profile Specification - 11.1.3.2 Texel Fetches](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.compatibility.pdf#page=478&zoom=100,168,764)

In both cases, the offset argument is integral because it is meant to access neighboring texels. See further [OpenGL Shading Language 4.60 Specification - 8.9.1. Texture Query Functions](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#texture-functions).

Comment: "*The difference between textureLodOffset and texelFetchOffset are only the texture coordinates.*" LOD respects filtering, texel fetch does not.

Comment: In fact, texelFetch respects almost none of the sampling parameters. Edge sampling (outside of the [0, w/h/d) range) causes UB, not clamping/repeating/etc.